# Максимальная длина данных в сессии

Tags: сессия, php

Какой максимальный объем информации может поместиться в сессии по умолчанию ? Я вот ложу в нее сериализованный массив с разными id, когда их сдесяток все нормально разумеется, а что если пользователь занесет 500-700 таких (навряд ли такое случится, но мало ли), стоит ли ожидать сюрпризов ?

Comment: Зависит от сервера. От количества памяти, уделяемого скрипту.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вы можете занести столько данных. сколько хотите. 
Все сессии хранятся на сервере. Единственное  - Вы можете достичь максимального лимита памяти для скрипта, который по умолчанию равен 128 Мб, что маловеротно

Comment: Полезно знать)